# Requesting feedback on proof of theorem

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I'm trying to self study my way through Apostol's calculus and have just started.  Having completed an undergraduate degree in physics some time ago, the math courses I took mostly focused on calculation and much less on proofs, so I'm a bit unsure of myself when doing proofs.  Any feedback on correctness, form, style, or otherwise would be most appreciated.

The theorem is from Volume 1, page 20:

Theorem 1.24:  If $a b>0$, then both $a$ and $b$ are positive or both are negative.

Proof: Assume the contradiction: if $a b>0$ if one of $a$ or $b$ is positive and the other is negative.  Without loss of generality we will assume $b$ is positive and $a$ is negative.  This means by assumption that $(-1 \cdot a b) > 0$.  Because $a b$ is positive this would mean that $-1 > 0$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore $a$ and $b$ must both be positive or negative for $a b>0$. $\square$

Axioms for the real numbers, introduced to this point, have been (ref Apostol):

1. Commutative laws
2. Associative laws
3. Distributive laws
4. Existence of identity elements
5. Existence of negatives
6. Existence of reciprocals
7. If $x$ and $y$ are in $R^+$, so are $x+y$ and $xy$.
8. For every real $x \neq 0$, either $x \in R^+$ or $-x \in R^+$, but not both.
9. $0 \notin R^+$

Comment: ORR you can just put $a, b \neq 0$ and show $-a*-b = ab$..........

Comment: You'd best let us know what axioms and theorems have already been introduced to you.

Comment: Challenge: can you prove this without using any number other than $0$ and without relying on commutativity? It turns out that this theorem holds in any totally ordered ring—not just the real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading Apostol's calculus for self study too.Here's my proof.

My approach is first to prove that $a$ and $a^{-1}$ $(a \neq 0)$ are both negative or positive.

Suppose $a>0$ and $a^{-1}<0$, and then by axiom 8 we have $ (-a)^{-1}>0$ (I'm using a fact $-(a/b)=(-a/b)=a/(-b) \textbf{ if } b \neq 0.$ from exercise 9 in the $*I \space 3.3 \space Exercises$.This fact influences many step below.)

Then we have $a * (-a)^{-1} = -1 > 0$ by axiom 7. But in the theorem 1.21 we have $1>0$,this against the axiom 8 that **For every real x≠0, either x∈R+ or −x∈R+, but not both.** so $a^{-1} must > 0$ if $a>0$.
same thing if we suppose $a<0$ and $a^{-1}>0$. and use the expression $(-a)*a^{-1}$ to lead to the contradiction.

having the lemma above in hands.we can prove the theorem now.

suppose $a>0$,so we have $a^{-1}>0$,then by axiom 7 we have $ab*a^{-1} = a*a^{-1}*b =b>0$

if $a<0$,we have $-a^{-1}>0$,then $ab*(-a)^{-1} = -b >0$ so $ b < 0$.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the contrapositive: if $a,b$ have opposite signs, then $ab<0$.